# How to rotate text in canvas in SwiftUI?

Tags: canvas, swiftui, text, rotation

I didn't find the way to rotate text at 90° in the canvas using the context in SwiftUI (iOS 16).

Here is my code:

```
Canvas { context, size in

  context.rotate(by: Angle(degrees: 90)) // doesn't work because it surely rotates all the canvas
            
  let text = Text(String(drinkFrom)).font(.custom("HelveticaNeue", size: 12)).foregroundColor(.textUnselected)
     
  //.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90), anchor: UnitPoint(x: drinkFromOriginX, y: size.height/2)) // doesn't work because it's can't be resolved by the context
            
     context.draw(text, at: CGPoint(x: drinkFromOriginX, y: size.height/2), anchor: .center)
    }
 }
```

I would like to rotate the text around it's center, using its position.
What did I miss ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new layer and modify that one independently  from the main context:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Canvas { context, size in
                        
            let text = Text("Example Text")
                .font(.headline).foregroundColor(.blue)
            
            context.drawLayer { ctx in // adds a layer that can be indepentently modified
                ctx.translateBy(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2) // move to center
                ctx.rotate(by: Angle(degrees: 90)) // rotate
                ctx.draw(text, at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), anchor: .center) // draw text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note the order of things. The drawLayer gets translated and THEN rotated. They are not interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks ChrisR and Yrb. I adapted it for my needs (as a function to be used multiple times, change local position...). It works very well.